# Storing information and getting it back from currentThread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

There is a class called `Data`, which is called my other classes. `Data` class is accessed by many threads, I want to store some information on each thread. Specifically, `Data` has an instance called `name`(String), I want to store this `name` to the thread which is creating the Data object.

Down the line, I wish I could able to access `name` by getting `currentThread()` some where else in the code.

I’m very new to Java, is it possible?

Comment: So are you creating a unique object Data per thread and having a container, or are you going to create this object and then run the threads, all accessing the same object?  It sounds like the initial way

Comment: If you want each thread to have its own name (of String type), then why not use one of Thread constructor Thread(String name) or Thread(Runnable, String). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#constructor_detail

Comment: First way, unique Data per thread.

Comment: @batman: If it is unique Data (assume you mean object) per thread, then there is no thread-safety involved. The thread-safety can be applied only when ONE Data object is shared by all threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Data object might need to have member fields of type http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html if I am reading your question correctly. Those member fields that are ThreadLocal will have a different value depending on the thread accessing it.